# Dúvida Laravel 5 - Bibliotecas e Funções

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
 <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\ListaProduto;
    use App\Produto;
    use Input;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
    use Session;

    class ProdutoController extends Controller {

        # Página de Exibir Produtos
        public function getAdicionar(){
            return view('backend.produtos');
        }
    }
```

Estava até pouco tempo desenvolvendo sites e sistemas utilizando o **Laravel 4**. E agora estou migrando para o **Laravel 5**.

Estou percebecendo que algumas funções antes existentes no 4, deixaram de estar compiladas no 5. Um exemplo:

A biblioteca **Facade/HTML**.

Estou tendo que instalar essa biblioteca em todo site que crio o projeto no **Laravel 5**. Beleza, isso é o de menos. Digita no arquivo *composer.json* e mandar rodar.

Porém, algo acontece comigo que eu não sei se é normal, se é nativo do **Laravel 5** ou se é apenas um comando que eu preciso fazer para que não aconteça mais.
No código que postei acima vejam as primeiras linhas:

```
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\ListaProduto;
use App\Produto;
use Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Session;
```

Toda vez que vou usar alguma função preciso declarar. Antes, no 4, comigo, não era assim. Até mesmo um **Model** preciso dizer para o código que vou lhe usar. Se eu quero usar a tabela **Produto**, tenho que descrever `use App\Produto;` e assim por diante com `Session`, com `Cookies`, com `Hash`.

### Perguntas

1 - Isso é realmente necessário ? 
2 - Tem algo que eu possa fazer para reverter isso ?

Comment: +1. Essa pergunta é muito importante para quem está querendo migrar do Laravel 4 para o 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provalvemente, o pessoal do `Laravel`, ao desenvolver a versão `5`, verificou possíveis problemas com o conflito de nomes de classes e então resolveu adotar o `namespace` para que isso não ocorresse.

## Explicação

No Laravel 4, por exemplo, eu não poderia ter  uma tabela chamada `events` na minha aplicação, pois se eu criasse o model `Event`, por essa classe já existir  no `Laravel 4`, geraria um erro.

> Cannot redeclare class `Event`

## Isso é realmente necessário ?

A meu ver, se há um possível problema de colisão de nomes, você deveria evitá-lo. Mas no geral, se você acha que você pode manter isso sob controle, você pode instalar os pacotes do `Illuminate\Facade` via composer e configurá-los da mesma maneira do Laravel 4.

Aqui está um pequeno exemplo:

https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/02/install-illuminatehtml-laravel-5/

## Tem algo que eu possa fazer para reverter isso ?

Talvez uma das formas de resolver isso seria utilizando o `BaseController` e instanciando algumas coisas que serão reutilizadas ao longo do projeto.

Exemplo teórico:

```
use Illuminate\AlgumPacote\Input;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   { 

      $this->input = new Input();
   }

   public function input()
   {
       return $this->input;
   }
}



class ProdutoController extends BaseController
{
  public function getIndex()
  {
     $this->input()->get('teste');
  }
}
```

Comment: Respondeu em partes.